# Field 'chewieController' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

im try some code to get video from database mysql with flutter. but i have problem with the 'chewiecontroller' has not been initialized i had try to change the late variable with 'ChewieController? chewieController' but still error. any solution for that problem?
This is my current code:

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class PlayVideoChewie extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  const PlayVideoChewie({required this.url});

  @override
  State<PlayVideoChewie> createState() => _PlayVideoChewieState();
}

class _PlayVideoChewieState extends State<PlayVideoChewie> {
  late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  late ChewieController chewieController;

  Future initializeVideo() async {
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url);

    await videoPlayerController.initialize();

    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
    setState(() { });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeVideo();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Playvid"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 250,
        child: chewieController != null &&
                chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
            ? Chewie(
                controller: chewieController,
              )
            : Container(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

any help will be valuable for me. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you have to

```
await videoPlayerController.initialize();
```

chewieController is only initalize after that, so it cause error.
Change it like this :

```
class _PlayVideoChewieState extends State<PlayVideoChewie> {
  late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController? chewieController;

  Future initializeVideo() async {
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url);

    await videoPlayerController.initialize();

    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
    setState(() { });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeVideo();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (chewieController == null) {
      return Container(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Playvid"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 250,
        child: Chewie(
          controller: chewieController!,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. i tried this and its works. also there's typo in your solution code late TextEditingController videoPlayerController;

Comment: Aw yes my mistake, i edited

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when you call a `Future` from `initState`, if the result of it is needed for the first build. The `initState` function is not async, so you can't use `await` to wait for the result of `initializeVideo()`. So what happens is that the `build` method will run earlier than `chewieController` is initalized.

The proper solution is to implement a `FutureBuilder` in the `build` method.

You will get the `lateInitalization` error even if you try to check with the below line, because with the `late` keyword it will throw an error if you read a variable that has not been set:

```
if (chewieController == null)
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) on how to create a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ill remmember this

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to declare both variables like that?

```
ChewieController? chewieController;
VideoPlayerController? videoPlayerController;
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but it doesn't work on me.