# LateInitializationError in using chewie to display videos

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a video using chewie in Flutter but when using it I get the error LateInitializationError.
I use these codes:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:video_box/video_box.dart';

class Player extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  const Player({Key? key,required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Player> createState() => _PlayerState();
}

class _PlayerState extends State<Player> {
  bool loadedData = true;

  late ChewieController _chewieController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: loadedData? const Center(
        child: RefreshProgressIndicator(),
      ):
      Chewie(controller: _chewieController),
    );
  }

  void loadData() async{
    var url = Uri.https('my api', {'q': '{http}'});
    var response = await get(url);
    var link = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    String videoLink = link['videoLink'];

    setState(() {
      String link = videoLink;
      late final VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
          Uri.parse(link)
      );
      late final ChewieController _chewieController = ChewieController(
          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
          aspectRatio:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
      );
      _videoPlayerController.initialize();
      loadedData = false;
    });
  }
}
```

I want to get the movie link via api. But when I use this link in the codes, I get an error.
how can i fix this error???

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74095538/field-chewiecontroller-has-not-been-initialized

Answer (score 0):

```
  late final ChewieController _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
  );
```

here you are putting the controller in a local variable, which you don't want. You want to set the state's controller so just change it to

```
  _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
  );
```